# Check if loaded DLL is system module

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, dll

What are the ways to reliably check if loaded DLL is official Microsoft's module/library?

Checking the digital signature? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file

Is there any other way?

Is there any supported windows API (like `IsSystemModule` that allows me to check if it's a system module (`C:/windows/system32`, `C:/windows/SysWOW64`)? It can still be loaded from executable folder though...

Comment: If you're worried about loading a malicious DLL, then by the time you've loaded it, isn't it too late?

Comment: @user253751 It has nothing to do with detecting malicious DLL in this case, injecting through LoadLibrary is not as common anymore :P

Comment: Would a DLL from a different version of Windows still count as "Microsoft official"?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, it would still have a digital signature.

Comment: What's wrong with checking the signature?

Comment: @klutt nothing wrong. The question is, is there any official helper that checks specifically for Microsoft's signature.

Comment: What is the purpose of this, by the way? It seems useless to me.

Comment: @user253751 The purpose of this is to filter the list of loaded libraries so I could apply a different colouring in a GUI for system libraries for example. There are many use cases. I think I will need to write a helper for this by myself.

Comment: okay, "different colouring in a GUI" is a pretty sensible reason. I was just wondering.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, or just hide those libraries completely in a list.

Comment: If you look at Microsoft/SysInternals' Autoruns tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), it checks the Authenticode signature. I think it's the best way.

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks, looks sensible. I will implement that.

Answer (score -1):

Other than signature check, you can check the VERSIONINFO resource for (C) Microsoft. This is a quick and dirty check, not a solid authentication though.

Comment: Anyone can link a `© Microsoft Corporation` Copyright property into their binaries' version resources. Not something you'd want to recommend using.

Comment: This is for COLOR CODING in the GUI, not for honest authentication. The OP is putting together some kind of a process explorer, wants to tell between user binaries and OS ones. OSVERSION will do as a first order approximation.

Comment: No, this is **not** about color coding. The question is asking, how to identify certain modules. The OP may be using it for color coding. But the question is much more generic. This is going to misinform any future visitor, that happens to not use the information to change the color of some pixels in their GUI.